# Read value and add error in Filter Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following ASP.NET MVC filter attribute:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
  ControllerBase controller = context.Controller;      
}
```

And on the view I have a form with

```
@Html.TextBox("Captha");
```

And my model is:

```
public class SignUpModel {
  public String Email { get; set; }
  public String Password { get; set; }
  public String Captcha { get; set; }
}
```

How can I, in my filter attribute, do the following:

1. Get value inserted in the text box;
2. Add an error to model state if there is no value or a specific condition is false?
3. Do I need the captcha property in my model?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: What value do you want to insert in your TextBox? What is your ActionFilter supposed to do?

Comment: Basically, I need to read the text inserted in the textbox and compare it with a session value. If they are different then I want to add an error to the model state so it displays in the view on a validation helper

Comment: Can you post your Model?

Comment: Just did ... But do I need the captcha property in my model?

Comment: Can't I access, in an action attribute, a value inserted in a form element?

Comment: Do you need to compare Captcha with a value in the session or not? Why is your updated question different from what you asked in the comments?

Comment: Yes, I need to compare the value inserted in the text box with the Session value ...

Comment: My idea is to have a Captcha action filter which, on OnActionExecuted, generates the question, and adds it to ViewBag, and the Answer and adds it to the Session. Then when the form is submited the same filter, on OnActionExecuting would get the insert value on the form and compare it to the session variable. If different then add it to model state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an ActionFilter to do this. Use `CompareAttribute` in your model to validate the Captcha property. Add another property to your model, and call it `SessionValue`, then use the `CompareAttribute` to compare the value entered for the `Captcha` property with the `SessionValue` property:

```
public class SignUpModel {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("SessionValue")]
    public string Captcha { get; set; }
    public string SessionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your  Controller action set the value of the `SessionValue` property to the value stored in the Session:

```
var model = new SignUpModel();
model.SessionValue = Session["MyValue"];
return View(model);
```

And, in your View, you'll have:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SessionValue)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Captcha)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Captcha)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to have `SessionValue` as a hidden input in your View, you can create a custom validation attribute like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

public class MyCustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        string compareValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];

        return (string)value.Equals(compareValue);
    }
}
```

And, use it in your Model like this:

```
public class SignUpModel {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MyCustomValidation]
    public string Captcha { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: With your approach will I not need to have the SessionValue as an hidden input on my view? That is not safe ...